# How can you use CHM files well in Chromebook?

Tags: chromebook, chm, usability

I need CHM files for my research work because of their better search capabilities than PDF. I have not found any way to read [CHM (Compiled HTML)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help) files on a Chromebook. They are the faster way to read my files than PDF because of indexed search and local search in section.

Unsuccessful CHM viewers in Samsung Chromebook 2012-october 11" with 2GB

- Chumium beta - it does not even open my CHM files but the view stays white all the time

I am also open other fileformats which has similar capabilities than CHM. However, PDF is not one of them.

How can you search and read CHM files in Chromebook?

Comment: I think this may be a question for Software Recommendations.SE as you probably need additional software.

Comment: @Chenmunka No. I think such a software does not exist. I am trying to understand the system first so I think then the possibilities.

Comment: Would running a 'proper' linux instance be an option? I'm not super familar with the options but you might find a better chm viewer. What formats would work for you?

Comment: Yes! Definately. Linux server is also possible but would be great to run the linux instance in Google's server.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an online viewer to view CHM files.

One such is the [SumatraPDF webapp](http://saturn.cameyo.com:8080/client.xhtml?id=c/play&appName=SumatraPDF&token=d1535359-f745-4695-91d0-c89c9d51c7f4) that can directly view CHM files.
Viewing time is severely limited unless you register for a free Cameyo account,
but is enough for verifying one example CHM file (it worked with mine).

[Zamzar](http://www.zamzar.com/) will, for a fee, convert your CHM files to PDF and store them online for viewing.
The cheapest plan is $9 per month, allowing a maximum file size of 200 MB
and online storage of 5 GB.

---

As you mention a Linux server, this gives more options :

1. Using [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/), you can use the original reader from Windows under Linux : [hh.exe](http://wiki.winehq.org/hh)
2. [KchmViewer](http://www.ulduzsoft.com/linux/kchmviewer/) is the standard KDE viewer for CHM files.
3. [xCHM](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xchm/) is another Linux viewer for CHM files.
4. [Okular](https://okular.kde.org/) might be another.
5. [FBReader](https://fbreader.org/) is an EBook reader that supports CHM.
6. You might find more readers by `apt-cache --names-only search chm`.
7. Firefox users can install the [ChmFox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/chmfox/).

I have not used any of these products, so cannot advise which one is the best for you
(hh.exe might be the best bet).

Comment: conversion wouldn't really work for the OP, considering what he's said.

Comment: Sumtra is great proposal. Is there any open-source software which I can set on my server for same task?

Comment: Sumtra is great proposal. Is there any open-source software which I can set on my server for same task?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: I think that there are no perfect solutions for the Chromebook, but online viewers might be better than nothing.

Comment: True, but the conversion option isn't really within what's asked for.

Comment: @Masi: That depends on the server. But if you have a server, why can't you install a reader on it?

Comment: Do you have any proposal about readers in Linux? It will take me now 1-2 weeks to get sufficient server power to do first tests about CHM readers.

Comment: Added some suggestion above.

Comment: Is there any Linux-equivalent for hh.exe? hh.exe is superfast in my i3. Much faster than any OSX-program which I have used. It seems that hh.exe is closed code.

Comment: Yes, there is : hh.exe itself, running on Linux thanks to Wine (Windows programs on Linux). hh.exe is the program that Windows uses to display chm files, and according to the link above it is included in the Wine release.

Comment: I love your answer! I support the claim that Wine is the first choice where you install hh.exe directly. It would be nice to understand what are current limitations of Wine. 5-10 years ago, it was still rather immature.

Comment: Is there any estimate how much Debian Linux 8.1 (for instance) Wine hh.exe stays behind pure Windows 10 hh.exe?

Comment: Probably not at all - hh.exe on my computer dates from 2010. It's not any more in development by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Chrome extension, currently in Beta, that will read CHM files.

It is called [Chumium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chumium-chm-file-reader/ihfoglidabnbmgpfibclmibdpgemobgi?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon).

This will run in the Chrome browser in your Chromebook.

Comment: Yes, I know Chumium. It is very buggy. It does not even open my CHM files.